# get name from fom two table with foreignkey

Tags: android, json

### Table -article-

### id |nam|image|id_categor(FK)|

table category

---

### id  |categorieName|

I have two tables in the database. The first table has a foreign key to the second table. Can I get name from the second table by the foreign key ?

need a JSON like

```
"categories":[
    {"categorieName":"test1",
             "data":[
        {
            "name":"wallpaper1",
            "image":"tv_101.jpg"
        },
        {
            "name":"wallpaper2",
            "image":"tv_102.jpg"
        }

    ]
```

Comment: Some infos about SQL Joins: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome, You need to provide a better description with a better code so everyone can understand easily.

If I understand your problem properly then you need a `join`. You can use [SQLite rawQuery](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#rawQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20android.os.CancellationSignal)) to get the desired output.

For Example:

```
private final String JOIN_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM article a INNER JOIN categories b ON a.id=b.other_id WHERE b.property_id=?";

db.rawQuery(MY_QUERY, new String[]{String.valueOf(propertyId)});
```

**EDIT:** I still don't get your question but I think you are using `PHP`

First of all you cannot directly get the `JSON` from the database. What you need to do is:

1. Query your required data using `PHP`

   `SELECT * FROM categories` then loop it in php and get all `articles` in each `category` by querying `SELECT * FROM articles WHERE cate_id=loopCategoy_Id`
2. And save it in a key value `array`
3. Then convert the `array` into `JSON`
4. Send JSON response

Comment: Getting data from MYSQL into JSON using PHP, I have 2 Table -articles-, and
Table -cottage- withe foreign-key -> id_categorie. my problem is getting the data like {
    "categorieName":"test1",
    "data":[
        {
            "title":"wallpaper1",
            "link":"tv_101.jpg"
        
       ]

Comment: Update your question and be clear that you have MySQL database and you want to get data from 2 tables. Upload your table schema and desired json output.

Comment: +-------+-----------+----------+
|  id   |    name   |  cate_id   |   1> table item
+-------+-----------+----------+
    +-------+-----------------
   |  id      |  categori  |           2-> table cate
   +-------+-----------+-

relation (FK) between to databases and bring this as JSON (using php).  need a JSON like
{
    "item": [{
      
        "categori  1": {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "sampleCar",
           
        }
    , {
    
        "categori  2": {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "betterCar",
           
        }
    }]
}

Comment: @MomoMomo answer updated. I still didn't get your question and your json is not even parsable. Secondly when people say Update your question that means you need to update the question/description not the comment. Thanks

Comment: i ' m sorry brother

Comment: No problem we are here to help, hope you solved the problem

Answer (score -1):

Did you try **join** ? 
Joining two tables by common columns will definitely help here